# Integrating neo4j with jersey and tomcat

Tags: jersey, tomcat7, neo4j

I'm using the java embedded version of the neo4j (v. 1.7.02), created a small project using Chypher for quering the db and everythings works ok.
Now I'm trying to deploy it on Tomcat to work as web app, hence I created a REST service using Jersey.
The REST works fine too, but without neo4j.

I'm really struggling to get neo4j running and connecting within the webservice REST project, I'm not sure where to locate the tb and how to config it to get neo4j run fine with tomcat. I uploaded neo4j libraries manually without maven.

I searched a lot on the web, with no luck.
Anyone knows where to place the neo db folder or where to find a basic conf for it?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
This is my connection to db:

```
// NEO4J SERVER START
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("neo4jdb");
```

this is my structure:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can share some code which uses how you use `neo4l` to access REST services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're having trouble with Tomcat and Neo4j. They really shouldn't have anything to do with each other. Your application in standalone mode with embedded neo4j works fine it appears. Then it should also work when run in a container. How does your app connect to neo4j? The neo4j folder can be anywhere- as long as you specify the path to it when you construct an Embedded database server.

Comment: Why do you have the db in lib? I think you should move it out of there- especially if it ends up being packaged in your war and re-deployed. Keep it outside tomcat somewhere and make sure you give the full path in new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("neo4jdb");